# Offset for UTC to Daylight Savings Time incorrect

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I am trying to set a time to EST, and then find what it UCT time is. (We have our reasons).. I have read that "Eastern Standard Time" should take into account the Daylight savings time. But when we check the date, and we know it falls within Daylight Savings time, it still tries to convert for 5 hours instead of 4. Is there any method I am missing? Or do we have to do some manipulation.

```
DateTimeOffset convertDateTime = new DateTimeOffset(
      subbmission.EntryDate,
      TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time").BaseUtcOffset);
```

I added the following bu the boss is not a fan of using this..so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
if (zone.IsDaylightSavingTime(convertDateTime.DateTime))
{
   currentDateTime = convertDateTime.DateTime.AddHours(-1);
}
else
{
    currentDateTime = convertDateTime.DateTime;
}
```

Comment: You *did* call `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time").BaseUtcOffset`. Instead of the current offset, you requested the *base* offset, ie 5

Comment: You should be using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo)`. You're trying to convert to UTC, after all... But be aware that there are local date/time values which are ambiguous or skipped, and I can never remember what `TimeZoneInfo` does with those.

Comment: @JonSkeet this seems more clean, so this should convert the difference from utc from -5 to -4?

Comment: It will do the right thing based on the value you pass into it - but again, you should work out what you want it to do if the value is ambiguous or skipped.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, this worked for me...we were dancing all around it...But now I can't see where to mark it as answered. Marked your answers as useful though!

Comment: I'll add an actual answer - although it's fundamentally "Read the API documentation" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, you're using the wrong approach - if you want to convert to UTC, use [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495915(v=vs.110).aspx). You'll want to be careful around times that are either invalid (because they were skipped) or ambiguous (because the clock went back, and the same local time happened twice).

If you actually want a `DateTimeOffset` so that you can get both the local and UTC times, you could use call `ConvertTimeToUtc` then compute the difference between them. It's a shame that `TimeZoneInfo` doesn't appear to have a "construct a `DateTimeOffset` based on this `DateTime` in this time zone" but I can't see it...

As an alternative, you could use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project which makes all of this a lot clearer, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the correct offset for a date in the timezone (with or without daylight saing time), i use something like

```
DateTimeOffset utcOffset = new DateTimeOffset(subbmission.EntryDate.ToUniversalTime(), TimeSpan.Zero);
var zone TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

var correctOffset = zone.GetUtcOffset(utcOffset);
```